# JPA Discriminator Types Performance

Tags: java, performance, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I have a question about the performance difference between Integer and String discriminator types.
I am using Joined strategy, namely :

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class SuperClass
```

and I have some sub classes which are extending this super class. 
Which has a better performance? `DiscriminatorType.INTEGER` or `DiscriminatorType.STRING`?

Our provider is eclipselink and we are working on a massive volume of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "massive" exactly.

Comment: Performance depends on database type, index type, index size. Maybe this article will help you : [https://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2009/08/28/jpa-performance-dont-ignore-database-0](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2009/08/28/jpa-performance-dont-ignore-database-0). Anyway, try to run a benchmark test with both types String and Integer.

Comment: Thanks Andre. I did a benchmark and I found no major difference. Of course this is a test environment and certainly in production one the conditions will differ. As I understood eclipselink will generate queries in which it compares the discriminator column with discriminator value. So the only performance concern would be the comparison by a number or a string. In Oracle and on indexes I don't think of any big difference. does it?

Answer (score 2):

Normally using integer fields as the primary key column or index column or join would perform better if that is all you asking about.

But if you are really dealing with massive amount of data you may consider using SINGLE_TABLE instead of JOINED type inheritance if there are not many different attributes on the extending classes.

Because with JOINED type inheritance you need to do a extra join operation every time you need data. And also you should do 2 inserts for every insertion.